# Bash exclude lines where proportion of columns contain matched value

Tags: bash, awk

I have a lage text file that I would like to filter by excluding lines that have a number of columns matching a certain character. I had previously removed lines where all columns from 2 onwards contained a 0 or a . like so:

```
awk '{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i!~/^(\.|0)/) {
            print
            break
        }
}'
```

but now I would like it so that I would print lines that had less than a specific number of columns with this value (".").

For example with data:

```
A B C D E
0 1 . 0 0
1 ./. 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
0 0 . . 0
. ./. . . .
```

and a match value of 2 I would expect the bottom two lines to be excluded so that the output would be:

```
A B C D E
0 1 . 0 0
1 ./. 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{delete a; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++; if(a["."]>=2) next} 1' foo
A B C D E
0 1 . 0 0
1 ./. 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
```

It iterates all fields (`for`), counts field values and `if` 2 or more `.` in a record, restrains from printing (`next`). If you want to count the periods only from field 3 onward, change the start value of `i` in the `for`: `for(i=3; ...)`.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I went with in the end as it was the first answer that worked with my data.

Answer (score 3):

With awk:

```
$ awk '{c=0;for(i=1;i<NF;i++) c += ($i == ".")}c<2' file
A B C D E
0 1 . 0 0
1 ./. 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
```

Basically it iterates each column and add one to the counter if the column equals a period (`.`).

The `c<2` part will only print the line if there is less than two columns with periods.

With sed one can use:

```
$ sed -r 'h;s/[^. ]+//g;s/\.\. *//g;/\. \./d;x' file
A B C D E
0 1 . 0 0
1 ./. 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
```

`-r` enables extended regular expressions (`-E` on *BSD).

Basically a copy of the pattern space is stored in the `h`old buffer, then all but spaces and periods is removed.

Now if the pattern space contains two separate periods it can be deleted if not the pattern space can be e`x`changed with the hold buffer.

Comment: These are excellent answers thank you, I accepted @james-brown's answer as it was the first one I saw that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
A B C D E
0 1 . 0 0
1 ./. 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
0 0 . . 0
. ./. . . .

$ perl -ne '(@c)=/\.\/\.|\./g; print if $#c < 1' ip.txt 
A B C D E
0 1 . 0 0
1 ./. 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
```

- `(@c)=/\.\/\.|\./g` array of `./.` or `.` matches from current line
- `$#c` indicates index of last element, i.e (size of array - 1)
- So, to ignore lines containing 3 elements like `./.` or `.` use `$#c < 2`

Comment: :Thanks for the answer, how would I apply this from say column 3 onwards?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @spasic's answer, but easier (for me) to read!

```
perl -ane 'print if (grep { /^\.$/} @F) < 2' file
A B C D E
0 1 . 0 0
1 ./. 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
```

The `-a` separates the space-separated fields into an array called `@F` for me. I then grep in the array `@F` looking for elements that consist of just a period - i.e. those that start with a period and end immediately after the period. That counts the lone periods in each line and I print the line if that number is less than 2.

Comment: agree, this is cleaner.. not familiar with using `grep` on array.. @mattbawn  , this answer is easy to modify: `grep { /^\.$/} @F[2..$#F]` for 3rd column onwards, `@F[3..$#F]` for 4th column and so on

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is alright.

```
    awk '$0 !~/\. \./' file
    A B C D E
    0 1 . 0 0
    1 ./. 0 1 1
    1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: This does not _print lines that had less than a specific number of columns with this value (".")_. It just won't print lines that begin with `0 0` or `. .`.